# useEffect does not effected by Firebase Auth Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have a state that stores the information of a user, and whenever the value of this state is equal to null, I need the window to be a login window, but when I put it to get the user's value, the `useEffect` only seems to render twice ( because of a console message) and even though the auth value changes, it doesn't update.

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(auth.currentUser);
  }, [auth])

  if(user === null || user === undefined) {
    return ( <Login /> )
  } else {...}
```

The auth value takes some time to be returned, as the function uses firebase's `getAuth`. So at first, the value is null, but I need that even if it is null, it keeps rendering the login screen until the value is updated and the `useEffect` defines the user.

Comment: Show where does `auth` come from please

Comment: @Konrad firebase

Comment: @evolutionxbox is `auth` a reactive variable? If not it will not trigger a render, so it will not trigger the `useEffect`

Comment: @Konrad I don't think it is, no. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/use-firebase-authentication-in-a-react-app/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in `auth.currentUser` (and not the reference to the whole  `auth` object) put that in your dependency array of the useEffect hook, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setUser(auth.currentUser);
}, [auth.currentUser])
```

By just doing `[auth]`, which is *not*  a primitive, react checks for equality via `Object.is()`, which returns two objects as equal if they reference the same location in memory. So while using `[auth]` might work, there are no guarantees.

However, it isn't clear in your question if `currentUser` is a primitive or another object.

Comment: the `useEffect` hook will only run twice: once when the user logs in for the first time, and once when the user logs in for the second time. It will not run when the user logs out because the `auth.currentUser` value does not change.

Comment: @Zain_Ul_Din that makes sense when the user logs out, but OP didn't mentioned anything about logging out. If it isn't _meant_ to update more than twice that's a different issue. However, it seems to me like they expected it to update more than twice. Regardless of the underlying issue, once should declare dependencies in the effect hook as above.

Comment: I think you're answer is fine according to OP requirements.